# try executes full operation, despite error

Tags: python, try-except

```
a = []
b = [1,2,'x']


try:
    for i in b:
        a.append(i%4)
        
except:
    print('Not possible')

finally:
    print("It's over")

print(a)
```

Result:

```
Not possible
It's over
[1, 2]
```

I always thought `try` in python is similar to transactions; `commit()` and `rollback()` in SQL. So in a way, the operation would not return partial results, as it does in my case. This is a dummy case, for example, but does python offer solutions in a way it doesn't commit the change to a list if the error was imposed in the process? So it would return a blank list in this example.

Please note, I am aware of how to fix this problem, I am curious about solving the issue with a `try` & `except`.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) section of the tutorial in the documentation which explains how `try` statement work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try` is a catcher, patiently waiting for an exception to be thrown so that it can catch it and send the code down the `Except` block. The *only* way an exception will be thrown is if it executes code, so no, it won't automatically rollback. Note that:

1. The code inside the `Try` has no idea it exists within a `Try`-`Except` block.
2. Because of 1., if there was a rollback, Python would really be taking all of your content inside of the `Try` and storing changes or copies of it. You will certainly have nested `Try`s. If you import a package, some of the functions you use in it will have `Try`s inside. This means the stack would be keeping track of multiple copies of everything you do in the block. Note that in most (many?) DBMS's, you cannot start a second transaction without ending your first. This is not the case in python.

If you want to rollback the changes, you should do that in the first few lines of your `Except` statement.

Comment: Yes, I get it. So the only solution is to do a = [] in except? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @filtertips As in Ali Shanoon's answer, another solution is to make temporary variables in your `Try` block which store the data until you know that an exception will not be raised, and then end your `Try` block with assignments.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your operation in a list comprehension

```py
a = []
b = [1, 2, 'x']

try:
    a += [i % 4 for i in b]
except Exception:
    print("failed")
```

This way nothing will be appended to `a` since the list comprehension failed to instantiate.

Comment: I'd just drop the `a = []` and do `a = [<listcomp>]`. No need to incur the extra overhead of adding a list to another list

Comment: @C.Nivs Keep in mind that OP references `a` later. If you drop the `a`, you'd need to try except once again later on in the code. This solution allows OP to retain all the later code.

Comment: @Kraigolas true, in that case it might be better to put the new definition of `a = []` in the `except` clause

Answer (score 1):

In Python, anything occurring in a `try` will execute (as if it weren't in a try/except block at all) all the way until an Exception is encountered. At that point, it then proceeds to the `except` block(s). `finally` is executed whether `except` was entered or not (aka, it will always fire). `try/except/finally` is not meant to be atomic like SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new metaclass such that every class using this metaclass implement the `try`/`except` the way you mean.

For instance, you could define:

```python
from copy import deepcopy
import types


class TryExceptRollbackMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_attrs = {}
        for name, value in attrs.items():
            if name == "__init__" or not isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
                new_attrs[name] = value
                continue
            # We know from now on that we're dealing with a non-static function
            # If for some reason, a non-static method is defined without being passed self as an argument
            if value.__code__.co_argcount == 0:
                new_attrs[name] = value
                continue

            new_attrs[f"updated_{name}"] = TryExceptRollbackMeta.generate_updated_method(value)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, new_attrs)
    
    @staticmethod
    def generate_updated_method(func):
        def updated_method(*args, **kwargs):
            original = deepcopy(args[0])
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception {type(e)} has occured: {e}. Reverting state...")
                args[0].__dict__.update(original.__dict__)
                return None

            return result

        return updated_method


class Test(metaclass=TryExceptRollbackMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []

    def correct(self):
        for i in [1, 2, 3]:
            self.a.append(i %  4)

    def incorrect(self):
        for i in [1, 2, 'x']:
            self.a.append(i % 4)
```

Then, this would work like this:

```python
>>> test = Test()
>>> test.updated_correct()
>>> print(test.a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> test.updated_incorrect()
Exception <class 'TypeError'> has occured: not all arguments converted during string formatting. Reverting state...
>>> print(test.a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

By doing so, you have full control on the way you want to deal with an Exception, you can act according to the Exception type, print the line at which it failed, etc...

The problem is that the `deepcopy` can potentially be very long depending on what your object attributes are. It is still possible to target the attributes you want to revert specifically though, this is just the general case where you don't know which attribute can be affected by a method.